# Selenium Java -HtmlUnitDriver - Cant find any elements on page?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
   WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
    driver.get("MYURL");
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.id("your_name"));
```

The error is the following

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
Unable to locate element with ID: 'your_name'
For documentation on this error, please visit: 
https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
 System info: host: 'DESKTOP-0DI3NHE', ip: '192.168.0.45', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
  Driver info: driver.version: HtmlUnitDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementById(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1251)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:2020)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:2016)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.implicitlyWaitFor(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1642)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:2016)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElement(HtmlUnitDriver.java:794)
```

This is the html of the page when looked at through chrome developer tools

```
<input id="your_name" class="hinted hintshown" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name (required)" value="" tabindex="1" style="background: rgb(247, 247, 247);">
```

Comment: Your code shows `By.id("name")` - that's different from the error message.  Can you paste (NOT typing a copy) the following three items :   your code, the actual error message, and the HTML showing the element with that id.   We need all these to be sure of the problem.   Edit the question with these lines (as opposed to pasting them as a comment)

Comment: i added correct info

Comment: @DanielHaughton can you check if there is any iframe present in the html structure above the element you are trying to access

Comment: There are google ad Iframes on the page before that element, but they are not parents of the form or input field

Comment: Thanks @DanielHaughton, Must admit I was hoping to spot something like one having "_" and the other "-" ;)   There are a few differences between ChromeDriver and HtmlUnitDriver - eg, HtmlUnitDriver doesn't run Javascript by default, so try adding `driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true)` before calling `.get("url")`.   Also, have you tried with ChromeDriver?

Comment: new HtmlUnitDriver(true); is the same as driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true) to my knowledge. I will try chrome driver

Comment: Sorry - yes you're right about HtmlUnitDriver(true).   The other thing to try is `getPageSource()` to see what is on the page that it's got, and compare it to Chrome's.

Comment: Any waiting for loading the page?

Comment: No it is exactly as written, any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: @DanielHaughton Wait for the element to be loaded (become visible): `WebDriverWait waitUpToFiveSeconds = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000); waitUpToFiveSeconds.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeVisible(By.id("your_name")));`

Comment: My IDE doesn't seem to pick up elementToBeVisible

Comment: There is difference between ExpectedCondition and ExpectedConditions. You need ExpectedConditions. See https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/selenium/selenium-expected-condition-example/